# How to pass data to an event handler C#

Tags: winforms, datatable, datagridview, combobox, event-handling

I want change which DataTable gets fed to a DataGridView depending on the value of a Combobox. How do I pass the event handler my Dictionary containing the DataTables?

```
            this.PtCodesAndOffsets = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
            this.PtCodesAndOffsets.DataSource = DataTableList["Corridor - (1)"];
            this.PtCodesAndOffsets.Location = new System.Drawing.Point((Width / 3) * 2, 90);
            this.PtCodesAndOffsets.Height = (Height-40-90-50);
            this.PtCodesAndOffsets.AutoSizeColumnsMode=DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
            this.PtCodesAndOffsets.RowHeadersVisible = false;
            this.Controls.Add(PtCodesAndOffsets);

            this.CorridorDropDownPtClodesComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += CorridorDropDownPtClodesComboBoxEvent(DataTableList);

        }

        private void CorridorDropDownPtClodesComboBoxEvent(Dictionary<string,DataTable> DataList)
        {
            this.PtCodesAndOffsets.DataSource = DataList[this.CorridorDropDownPtClodesComboBox.Text];
        }
```

I tried customizing the event handle object to take in my Dictionary. But that Fails.

Comment: You cannot change the signature of an event handler. You can simply declare your Dictionary as a Field and access it in that method